# How to load datasets with 3 consecutive lines considered one?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
|T  2009-08-26 17:1...|  
|U  http://twitter....|  
|     W No Post Title|  
|                    |  
|T  2009-11-01 02:4...|  
|U  http://twitter....|  
|     W No Post Title|  
|                    |  
|T  2009-11-18 16:5...|  
|U  http://twitter....|  
|     W No Post Title|  
|                    |
```

right now i have the data like this
i want to group every 4 rows of data.

So one row will contain

```
T  2009-X-XX   U   http://xxxx      W xxxxxxx"
```

Is that possible?
Or is there anyway to make it into a csv file which the header will be T U and W?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the format consistent that it contains an empty line every 3 lines (that should be considered one)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only solution would be to write your own custom [TextBasedFileFormat](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormat.scala#L160) that would handle 3-line text format like yours.

See [org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVFileFormat.scala) for inspiration.

---

It may be possible that `CSVFileFormat` could handle the format with ease with empty lines as line separator.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily merge your rows if you can get them in the following dataframe format:

```
+-------+--------------------+
|line_nr|                line|
+-------+--------------------+
|      0|T  2009-08-26 17:...|
|      1|U  http://twitter...|
|      2|     W No Post Title|
|      3|                    |
|      4|T  2009-11-01 02:...|
|      5|U  http://twitter...|
|      6|     W No Post Title|
|      7|                    |
|      8|T  2009-11-18 16:...|
|      9|U  http://twitter...|
|     10|     W No Post Title|
|     11|                    |
+-------+--------------------+
```

The you can do:

```
df
  .groupBy((floor(($"line_nr") / 4)).as("line_group"))
  .agg((concat_ws("", collect_list($"line"))).as("line"))
  .show(false)

+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|line_group|line                                                                              |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0         |T  2009-08-26 17:1...U  http://twitter....     W No Post Title                    |
|1         |T  2009-11-01 02:4...U  http://twitter....     W No Post Title                    |
|2         |T  2009-11-18 16:5...U  http://twitter....     W No Post Title                    |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```